# How do I manipulate the DOM when I using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, jquery-mobile

Do I use the [jQuery way](http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Manipulation)?  Or jQuery Mobile also provides functions to manipulate the DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile includes jQuery so you do it in jQuery way.

Also note that jQuery Mobile does not generate final DOM until the page init events are called:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Note separate events for pages loaded using AJAX (on by default)

Comment: +1 but, JQuery mobile does not include JQuery, it depends on it to work. So you need to import it first. Simple clarification. http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use standard jQuery techniques for DOM manipulation.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc1/docs/about/intro.html says:

> jQuery’s mobile strategy can be summarized simply: A unified user
>   interface system that works seamlessly across all popular mobile
>   device platforms, built on **the rock-solid jQuery and jQuery UI
>   foundation**. Focused on a lightweight codebase built on progressive
>   enhancement with a flexible, easily themeable design.